# Sharing simple data between two processes

Tags: android, local-storage, sharedpreferences

I'm developing an android application, which when user enters licence code, retrieves from web service some simple key-value data and saves to sharedpreferences.

My app also have a service, which starts on separate process and it needs to get a part of previously saved data from sharepreferences.

My main app lets say is in "com.foo.myMainApp" package. And my service is "com.foo.myMainApp/myService".

The problem is, that the service can't access main program's shared prefs, because they are saved in different location.

I'm struggling with this problem for a couple of days and can't find a way out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

in Service

```
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("ACTION");
    broadcastIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "hello");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

In MainACtivity 
register this broadcast receiver and your good to go receiving messages.

```
   private class Message extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context,  Intent intent) {
           // get the message here
        }
    }
```

// register this onStart
        registerReceiver(new Message(),new IntentFilter("ACTION") );

hope this helps :)